# Wiring A Switch For A 240v Power Outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring

I want to add power outlets to a side of my garage that currently has none but am struggling to find wiring diagrams for a 240v switch that will be connected to an outlet. Is it as easy as 2 hots connected to the bottom two screws of a double pole switch and then 2 hots out of the top two screws with a ground wire attached? I just haven't had any luck finding anything to confirm this.

My garage functions as both a hobby space and where my kids store their bikes, scooters, etc. I want to wire switches upstream of the outlets so I can keep my tools plugged in and not be concerned about a child messing around and accidentally turning a tool on.

[image: Garage Wiring]

Comment: I take it the circuit breakers for your garage circuits are nowhere near the garage?

Comment: It is that simple, but don't underestimate yours kids willingness to activate more than one switch when they have a case of curiosity. I highly recommend a long and boring explanation of the dangers of each tool. Talk at least 2 minutes past their eyes glazing over.

Comment: The circuit breakers are in the same garage. I need outlets on the opposite side of the garage than the power panel. As for kids, my concern is with smaller children that could pull out the  switch on a table saw but not be tall enough to operate switches.

Comment: @Remy -- does the panel in the garage serve the whole house, or just the garage?

Comment: The panel serves the whole house including the garage. @ThreePhaseEel

Comment: Remy Another code mention that we regularly forget here. Tamper resistant receptacles are also required. 2020 NEC 406.12 all 15 & 20 amp 125- and 250v non locking-type receptacles ,,, in following ares shall be listed tamper-resistant. 406.12.1. Dwelling units including detached garages and accessory buildings. Washing state has adopted the 2020 code and unless the receptacle is a twist lock it requires a a tamper-resistant GFCI protected receptacle. Still requires GFCI for twist lock.

Comment: @EdBeal Does every outlet in a 125v string need to be tamper resistance & GFCI or can all be tamper resistant and just one be GFCI?

Comment: Both are required in / for all receptacles, the GFCI protection can be from the panel or a GFCI receptacle that the load terminals feed the rest of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch 240v there are 2 methods.
Cheap method single pole switch break 1 hot that’s it. the circuit is still live 120v could be measured to ground but a 240v device will be turned off.
I have seen this used extensively on heating circuits.
I have also found this in older tools like radial arm saws, and table saws that were multi voltage. The down side the tool has 120v potential to ground when off.
Advantage it’s cheaper.

Today The more common way is to use a double pole switch and break both hot legs.
This kills all power going to the tool
It cost a bit more.
Is considered safer because no power to the tool but a 240v device doesn't care.
Which method is used.

If you want to use standard snap switches on motors if not motor rated a switch with 2x the current requirement is needed.

For general loads ( other than motors) the switch only needs to be rated for the load.

Comment: I plan on running a 3HP table saw using a 6-15 outlet downstream of the switch. Would a double pole switch rated at 20amps not be correct for this application? I was considering a switch like this one: 

https://www.platt.com/platt-electric-supply/Industrial-Switches-20-Amp-Toggle-Switches/Leviton/1222-2W/product.aspx?zpid=34331

Comment: No, it is only 2 hp rated. Try a ms303-ds https://amzn.to/38aMAex 5 hp@ 240v

Comment: Do I have to have a motor rated switch if I am not using it to control the motor? My intent is not to turn the power on and off through the switch but to provide power to the outlet and then turn the table saw on.

Comment: Well by code a 3 Hp motor 240v is 17 amps so it should be at least a 30A unless motor rated for 3hp. The switch you have is only rated for 2 Hp. If you are only using it for a safety not opening and closing under load it might hold up. For circuit ampacity motors require 125% of the fla so you need a 20 amp circuit and receptacle also.

Comment: From the manual: "The Professional Cabinet Saw model number PCS31230 comes with an AC motor that is rated at 3 hp and operates at 60 Hz. It can be used with single phase 208-240V power. The motor draws 13 amps at 208-240V power." The saw uses as 6-15 plug so that means I have to use a 15amp circuit breaker to match it, correct? And I should be able to use this switch in case it was used unintentionally to start the saw:  https://www.platt.com/platt-electric-supply/Manual-Starters-Switches-Toggle-Type/Leviton/MS302-DS/product.aspx?zpid=214415

Comment: @NoSparksPlease The MS303-DS you referred to is non-grounded. Is it legal to use them when running new circuits (not replacing an existing component).

Comment: It needs to be mounted in a metal junction box to comply with grounding requirements in 404.9(B)(1).

Comment: Rely code requires the book value to be used 430.6.A1. The nameplate is only used for separate overloads. The disconnect if motor rated can be 115%430.110.A exception 1 the wiring 125% the overcurrent protection device up to 250% for an inverse time breaker (home panels) per table 430.52 . The 2x for a snap switch and 20 amps is still not enough with the nameplate 430.109.C.1. Code value for a 3 Hp at 208=18.7, 240=17 (table 430.248)  even the 80% rule a 20 amp switch it two small motor circuits require 125% of there book value. We are not messing with you but providing code req to do it right

Comment: @nosparksplease, I had never known of a metal box requirement so I checked your reference. You missed the OR to a non metallic box with integral means for connecting to a equipment grounding conductor. Most all snap switches have a ground screw and metal strap that the cover attaches to to fulfill this requirement, plastic boxes are allowed. No change in the 2020 code for 404.9.B.1

Comment: @Remy if it's in a metal junction box (and most of the time, an industrial switch like this *would be*), then **the switch grounds through its monting screws**.  (the ground wires are required to be attached to the metal box FIRST *anyway*, so this makes grounding easy).  Receptacles can't do that trick *unless* they're labeled "self-grounding".

Comment: @EdBeal I will be using metal boxes mounted to the surface of the sheetrock along with 3/4" eat conduit. If I did a 6-20 outlet for the table saw and a 20 amp breaker with 10 gauge wire, the Leviton MS302-DS switch should work right? 30 amps and rated for motors. https://www.platt.com/platt-electric-supply/Manual-Starters-Switches-Toggle-Type/Leviton/MS302-DS/product.aspx?zpid=214415

Comment: That switch will hold up, having the #10 wiring will be a good idea if the 20 amp breaker won’t hold and you have to increase in size then you would need to upsize to a 30 amp receptacle & breaker to be fully code compliant but for a load of under 16 amps 240v this would be approved.

Comment: @EdBeal Did you miss that the ms303 switches have no ground terminal? I can't see any way to satisfy condition (2), leaving option (1), a metal box the only solution

Comment: @nosparksplease, did you miss the op is using a metal box?

Answer (score 2):

A single receptacle has to be full circuit amperage [NEC 210.21(B)(2)], so the 15A (NEMA 6-15) receptacle would be connected to 15A breaker or you need a NEMA 6-20 or a duplex 6-15. Normally a 6-20R is a T-slot and will accept a 6-15P.

Also the 2020 NEC specifies 240v receptacles in garages now require GFCI protection too [210.8(A)(2)].

Comment: I don't believe Washington State requires the GFCI, am I reading this correctly?
008(B) Other than dwelling units – GFCI requirements.
(3) GFCI requirements. GFCI protection for personnel will not be required for:
(a) Three-phase receptacles unless specifically required elsewhere in the NEC; or
(b) Receptacles other than 125-volt, single phase, 15- or 20-ampere used for: recreational vehicle supply
equipment or for attachment of a mobile home supply cord.

Comment: I don't think you are. "008(B) Other Than Dwelling Units" correlates with "NEC 210.8(B) Other Than Dwelling Units".  008(A) modifications for 210.8(A)Dwelling Units only gives modifications to the NEC, if it were a complete replacement for that section then no GFCI's would be required at all.  And even then I think, due to the colon, the modification for non-dwelling unit only applies if used for RV or mobile home connection.

Comment: Remy if you are in Washington state they are on the 2020 code. The 2017 code req all 120v receptacles in garages to provide GFCI protection.  The 2020 code requires all 125v through 250v receptacles to have GFCI protection 210.8.A. And 210.8.A.2. I am a licensed electrician in Oregon and we have a reciprocal license agreement because our states have similar enforcement of the code. You may have a local exception i an not currently working on your side of the Columbia so I haven’t checked the exceptions but the 2020 code has been approved and is In use by Washington state. We are trying to help

Comment: @EdBeal Thanks for the help! I really do appreciate it. So a 240v GFCI breaker would be something like this for a Homeline panel: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-Homeline-20-Amp-2-Pole-GFCI-Circuit-Breaker-Clear-Packaging-HOM220GFIC/204355351

Comment: Yes that breaker would meet code requirements for the 240v GFCI. Thanks on the site are up votes and or accepting an answer the check mark it shows the information was useful or you used it. You can upvote multiple items or answers but only accept 1.

Answer (score 0):

### While your approach with switched receptacles works...

While your approach using an external switch to control the receptacles *works*, and can be made fairly robust using a key-operated lightswitch like what's shown below:

[image: Leviton 1221-2WL]

, it does have the downside that you need to give each circuit its own switch, which doesn't scale as you add circuits.

### The alternative: feeder and lockoff

A more scalable alternative to the individual keyed switches is to reroute the shop circuits to a main lug subpanel in the garage, then put a *breaker lockoff* device and a suitable padlock on the feeder breaker for the shop.  That way, you have only one thing you need to unlock and lock to turn the shop on and off.

Similarly, you could use a main breaker in the subpanel with a locked on the subpanel's door.  You could even implement it using a separate lockable switch or breaker in its own box; this would allow you to use a breaker (such as an ABB/GE S800U or Schneider Electric/Square-D Multi9 C60BP) that can be fitted with both a lockoff and an *undervoltage release* coil, which allows you to implement a shop-wide E-stop function for a price that's not completely eye-watering.

Comment: I highly recommend your final suggestion.  I did something similar in my recently built workshop.  I have a subpanel with a main breaker and locking cover that feeds all the larger tools.  I can lock them all down by shutting off the main breaker and locking the panel door.